# It is not displayed correctly with firstUpdated ()

Tags: vaadin, lit

I'm implementing a checkbox component using vaadin and lit.
I've implemented it according to the vaadin documentation, but I don't see the grouped checkboxes.

When debugging in the console, "render ()" is called first, followed by "firstUpdated ()".
So I know that the property values will be an empty array.

However, I don't understand why this happens even though I implement it like the sample.
How can I implement it correctly?

[vaadin document](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/checkbox/#indeterminate)

This is custom element.

```
import { customElement, state } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-checkbox/vaadin-checkbox-group'
import '@vaadin/vaadin-checkbox/vaadin-checkbox'
import { CheckboxElement } from '@vaadin/vaadin-checkbox';
import { Person } from '../../util/person';
import { getPeople } from '../../util/personUtil';


@customElement('checkbox-indeterminate')
export class CheckboxIndeterminate extends LitElement {
  @state()
  private items: Person[] = [];

  @state()
  private selectedIds: string[] = [];

  async firstUpdated() {
    this.items = await getPeople();
    this.selectedIds = [String(this.items[0].id), String(this.items[2].id)];
    console.log(`firstUpdated: ${JSON.stringify(this.items)}`);
    console.log(`firstUpdated: ${JSON.stringify(this.selectedIds)}`);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`render: ${JSON.stringify(this.items)}`);
    console.log(`render: ${JSON.stringify(this.selectedIds)}`);
    return html`
      <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing">
        <vaadin-checkbox
          .checked="${this.selectedIds.length === this.items.length}"
          .indeterminate="${this.selectedIds.length > 0 && this.selectedIds.length < this.items.length}"
          @change="${(e: Event) =>
            (this.selectedIds = (e.target as CheckboxElement).checked
              ? this.items.map((person) => String(person.id))
              : [])}"
        >
          Notify users
        </vaadin-checkbox>

        <vaadin-checkbox-group
          label="Users to notify"
          theme="vertical"
          .value="${this.selectedIds}"
          @value-changed="${(e: CustomEvent) => (this.selectedIds = e.detail.value)}"
        >
          ${this.items.map((person) => {
            return html`
              <vaadin-checkbox .value="${String(person.id)}">
                ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}
              </vaadin-checkbox>
            `;
          })}
        </vaadin-checkbox-group>
      </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    `;
  }
}


declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'checkbox-indeterminate': CheckboxIndeterminate;
  }
}
```

This is `getPeople()` method.

```
import { Person } from './person';

export async function getPeople(): Promise<Person[]> {
  return [
    new Person(1, "Aria", "Bailey"),
    new Person(2, "Aaliyah", "Butler"),
    new Person(3, "Eleanor", "Price")
  ]
}
```

This is `Person` class.

```
export class Person {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(id: number, firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `getPeople()` return? In the example in the documentation, it returns an object with a `people` property that is destructed (`const { people } = ...`)  and then assigned to the `items` property (`this.items = people`). This step is missing for your example, but it's not clear whether that's an actual omission or intended because your `getPeople()` returns something different.

Comment: In the example in the documentation, `export async function getPeople(): Promise<PeopleResult>` returns an object called `PeopleResult` with an array of `Person` and a number of `hierarchyLevelSize`. The `checkbox-indeterminate` sample didn't need the `hierarchyLevelSize`, so the `getPeople()` I made returns an array of `Person`. This method is `export async function getPeople(): Promise<Person[]>`. The `getProple()` I made just returns an array of 3 Persons.

Comment: Have you checked the `firstUpdated` log messages to verity that `getPeople()` actually returns a Promise with an array of three person objects? I tried running your code example, but with my own simple implementation of `getPeople()` since you didn't share yours, and it seems to work exactly as expected for me. If I change it so that the array is empty, then there will be an error in the browser console and the checkbox group will not be shown as you described.

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. I have included my `getPeople()` method in the question. In the console log, the `render()` method is called first, and the `items` are empty. After that, the `firstUpdated()` method is called, and `items` has three values in it. However, the list is not output on the screen.

Comment: I'm sorry. I found the cause. I had made a mistake in `tsconfig.json`. I had specified `ESNext` for `target`, so it was not outputting to the screen. Thank you very much for trying.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry. I found the cause. I had made a mistake in tsconfig.json. I had specified ESNext for target, so it was not outputting to the screen.